# Retrieve data from custom table in QuickBlox

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

I have a custom table in `QuickBlox`, I want to retrieve the data of that table

```
NSURL *topPlaceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.quickblox.com/data/TopChatPoints.json"];
NSURLRequest * jsonRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:topPlaceURL];
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:jsonRequest delegate:self];    

-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}
-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [jsonData appendData:data];
}

 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"MY TOP PLACE = %@",jsonArray);

}
```

but I am not getting the data as I am not passing the `auth key` how can I generate `auth key` and send it with my `NSURLRequest` ?

Comment: They have an iOS SDK, why don't you use it?

Comment: I don't find a method for retrieving data from custom table.

Comment: now I am getting data by using SDK in this format..
className:TopChatPoints                      
 createdAt:2013-01-04 12:20:46 +0000                      
 updatedAt:2013-01-04 12:20:46 +0000                      
 ID:50e6c91e535c121f660065d5                      
 parentID:(null)                      
 userID:11473                      
 fields:{
    placename = "Face of Man";
    total = 1;

how can I extract `placename`?

Comment: This is JSON. Have a look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Comment: if you use SDK - it will be an array if QBCOCustomObject objects, each object has 'fields' property. It is NSDictionary. 
Also Look at snippets project inside SDK